# element.setAttribute is not a function when trying to set href

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In order to avoid spam I've changed my link to a JavaScript function that decodes and sets the href when the link is clicked.

HTML:

```
<li><a id="email"><i class="fas fa-email"></i></a></li>
```

JS:

```
function decode(a) {
  return a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){
    return String.fromCharCode((c <= "Z" ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26);
  })
}

function openEmail(element) {
  var b = decode("DecodedMailToEmailAddress");
  element.setAttribute("href", b);
  element.setAttribute("onclick", "");
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('click', openEmail);
});
```

But every time I click the link I get the following error:

```
TypeError: element.setAttribute is not a function
```

And it specifically points to:

```
element.setAttribute("href", b);
```

(And the line after that, if I put it first)

What am I doing wrong? I used the onClick HTML attribute before this to call the openEmail(this) function, but I'm trying to implement a Content Security Policy and that considers onClick as unsafe-inline.

Thanks!

Comment: Event handlers are passed an event object, not the element involved with the event.

Comment: You would need `element.target` (but calling an event object "element" is misleading, so pick a different name)

Comment: @JohnColeman: That won't work if the icon inside the link is clicked.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the warning. Would `event.currentTarget` be more reliable?

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yep, that'd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pointy mentions, the event handler is passed an [**event object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), not an element.

Use `this.setAttribute(...)` instead. `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to.

Note that `element.setAttribute("onclick", "");` won't remove the event handler you add via `addEventListener`, use `removeEventListener` instead:

```
function openEmail(element) {
  var b = decode("DecodedMailToEmailAddress");
  this.setAttribute("href", b); // or just this.href = b;
  this.removeEventListener("click", openEmail);
}
```

You can learn more about event handling on [quirksmode.org](https://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers give a event property to the callback function. The element you're looking for can be found in event.target.

So the function becomes:

```
function openEmail(event) {
  var b = decode("DecodedMailToEmailAddress");
  event.target.setAttribute("href", b);
  event.target.setAttribute("onclick", "");
};
```

By the way, you can also use `event.target.href = …` and setting event handers is better done with `addEventListener` instead of setting `onclick`, like you do in another part of your code.

Comment: This won't work if the user clicks on the icon inside the link (which they will do because the link contains no other child).

Comment: You're right. A solution is to use `event.target.closest('a').setAttribute(…)`. This only works in modern browsers, though.